# can't call Backbone.collection's method from Backbone.View's method with require.js

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I want to call collection's method from the AppView. But It can't. My code is like this.

#### todolist.js

```
define(["todolist","todo"],function(TodoList,Todo){
    var TodoList = Backbone.Collection.extend({
            url: "/todos",
            initialize:function(){
                this.fetch();
                this.bind("add",this.update,this);
            },
            add:function(){
                console.log("added");
            },
            update:function(){
                    console.log("update!");

                    }
    });

    return TodoList;
});
```

## app.js

```
 define(["jquery","underscore","backbone","todo","todolist","todo_view"],
    function($,_,Backbone,Todo,TodoList,TodoView){
        var AppView = Backbone.View.extend({
                initialize:function(){
                    this.collection = new TodoList;
                    this.collection.update();
                },
                events:{
                    "keypress #new-todo":"create",
                },
                    create:function(e){
                        if (e.keyCode === 13){
                            var txt = $("#new-todo").val();
                            var todo = new Todo({title: txt});
                            this.collection.add(todo.toJSON());
                        }
                    }
                }
        );
        return new AppView({el: $("body")});
});
```

But I don't know why this.collection.update() method outputs undefined. Do you have any idea?
And my all code is here https://github.com/haradashinya/my-todo-redis

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mistake is in your `app.js` definition. It should return `AppView` not an instance of it, the instance should be created outside the module definition. As it is now, by the time it returns `todolist` is not yet defined.